# Synchronous loading of Base64-encoded images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64, webgl

I have a set of ~200 base64-encoded PNGs (all coming from a single shared JSON file) that I'd like to load directly in a loop as WebGL textures, without having to resort to callbacks/event handlers (for simpler code and less event handling overhead). Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

I know that the canonical way to load base64-encoded images is via data URIs. But it seems that setting the `src` property of an `Image` object does not actually decode the image data, but only queues it for asynchronous loading (meaning that uploading the `Image` object as a WebGL texture right after setting the `src` property fails; setting an `onload` handler that uploads the texture succeeds).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why? Why do you want to do it synchronously? JavaScript in the browser is not designed to run synchronously. You'll freeze the browser and potentially get a "This Script is taking too long to execute" dialog.

It's not hard to do with asynchronously so why not do it that way?

```
var loadTextureFromImage = function(url, callback) {
   // use cyan as the default color.
   var initialColor = new Uint8Array([0,255,255,255]);

   // make a texture with 1x1 pixels so we can use the texture immediately
   // while we wait for the image to load
   var tex = gl.createTexture();
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, 
                 gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, initialColor); 

   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() {
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
      callback(img);
   };

   return tex;
};

var loadTexturesFromImages(listOfImages, callback) {
   var numLeftToDownload = listOfImages.length;

   var checkFinished = function() {
     --numLeftToDownload;
     if (numLeftToDownload == 0 && callback) {
       callback();
     }
   };

   return listOfImages.map(function(url) {
     return loadTexturesFromImage(url, checkFinished);
   });
};
```

Here's some code to use the function above

```
var imagesToLoad = [
   "http://foo.com/image1.jpg",
   "http://foo.com/image2.jpg",
   "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...",
];

var textures = loadTexturesFromImages(imagesToLoad);
```

Now you can just start rendering. They'll all render in cyan and get updated to the images as they are downloaded/decoded.

If you want to wait until they are all downloaded then supply a callback to `loadTexturesFromImages`.

I guess the short answer to your question is, "No, you can not decode images synchronously". The long answer is if you want to decode them synchronously [you'll have to decode them yourself](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js). But now you're back to the issues mentioned above. Namely you'll freeze the browser and your users will likely get a dialog asking them if they want to kill the script.

Comment: I know that the asynchronous way is not hard, I already implemented and tested it before asking the question. It is just over-complicated and potentially slow. Its slow, because I got ~200 textures to load and each will incur the overhead of scheduling the decoding, scheduling the onLoad event handler, and executing it. And each texture is <20kB in size, so freezing the browser is not an issue.

Comment: Decoding it oneself using png.js or an emscripten-ed version of libpng is a neat trick, but kind of defeats the purpose of gaining performance.

Comment: Why do you think it will gain performance? Because decoding is async each image can be decoded in a different thread whereas synchronously that's not true. And, even if the browser decodes them on the same thread the overhead of responding to JavaScript asynchronously is so tiny that the difference should be pratically unmeasurable. So really the only different sync vs async is async has the chance to be massively faster, otherwise they're just different coding styles.